# Microsoft is dropping support for Edge Legacy. Is it time to formally drop support for it on SE?

Tags: discussion, browsers, microsoft-edge

Microsoft has [officially dropped support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge) for Edge Legacy (the EdgeHTML build), with the only supported version being the Chromium-based. The [supported browser listing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161) suggests the last two versions are supported, though with faster release cycles, that doesn't quite mean as much as it used to.

Is dropping support for Edge Legacy in the pipeline?

While IE 11 was supported for quite a while, I don't think Edge Legacy has the same reach it had, and it might be worth considering officially no longer supporting a dead browser. It might be potentially moot since on systems kept up to date, [the browser would be removed in a patch](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/03/microsoft-edge-is-dead-long-live-microsoft-edge) - but some folks may be stuck on older builds.

Comment: Did SE ever had implemented specific measures to deal with edge only bugs? There is one status-completed bug. I don't think they "supported" Edge, it just happened to work ...

Comment: Its in the [list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). I have a similar request for the removal of [IE 11 in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322637/maybe-its-time-to-formally-drop-support-for-ie-11) - and IE was basically "If it breaks we're not going out of our way to fix it". And yes, [this is me being cheeky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337986/135565)

Comment: Just as information: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: There is a major bug with Legacy Edge, you can’t perform any reviews, the button doesn’t work

Comment: @Ramhound Ooh, was this reported? If it is - might be useful to drop a link here so that the status can be updated if this one is implemented

Comment: [There was a question.  I pointed out that Edge is unsupported by Microsoft.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361361/submit-button-in-review-queues-remains-disabled#comment1205789_361361)